# Issue with C++ macros on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) using CPPCHECK

Tags: c++, linux, jenkins, redhat, cppcheck

At my employment we are working on a large C++ project on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6, soon to be RHEL 8. with Bash shell. We sometimes use Netbeans for editing source code, but I prefer to use vim. We are doing DevOps and Agile with two week sprints, and using Jenkins build engine with AccuRev for source control. Every time a code change is promoted in AccuRev, Jenkins automatically starts a new build of the code base. As part of that build, CPPCHECK is used to do static code analysis on the C++ source code.

In part of our system, we are using C++ macros to define unit test scripts. the macros are not fully defined, since we are allowing the unit test script developer to customize them for doing unit tests. This system works fine with no error at compile time with g++ compiler, and also there is no error at run time either.

However, when Jenkins does a build, and it uses CPPCHECK to analyze the code, it is generating

error-id: unknownMacro

text: There is an unknown macro here somewhere. Configuration is required. If SCRIPT is a macro then please configure it.

Here is an example of the C++ code we are using to complete partially defined C++ macro:

```
SCRIPT(SampleScript)

BODY()
{
    cout << "SampleScript running." << endl;
}
 
END_SCRIPT()
```

SCRIPT, BODY, and END_SCRIPT are C++ macros listed in an include file, but are not completely defined. On the Github site for CPPCHECK there is a supposed solution to this issue by using -I option, but I tried that and the missing macro CPPCHECK errors are still occurring.

This is the CPPCHECK command listed with its arguments, including the -I option, but so far this command is still generating "unknownMacro" error.

```
cppcheck \
   -I ./* \
    -j 4 \
    --xml-version=2 \
```

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "not completely defined" or "completing a C++ macro". A preprocessor definition is either defined, or it isn't. `-U` to `cppcheck` _undefines_ macros, and if you do that your code will not be valid any more, the way it is currently written.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply, the unknownMacro error occurs either with or without the -U option

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have many years experience with Unix and Linux, but was not aware of the following fix. The fix is to use the -I option with CPPCHECK, which I was doing, but I was doing the following in the Makefile with an asterisk:

```
cppcheck \
-I ./* \
-j 4 \
--xml-version=2 \
```

I just found out from another person that asterisk * is not recognized in Unix and Linux Makefiles, but IS recognized from the command line with Bash and other shells like I have known for a long time. So I removed the asterisk from the CPPCHECK call and now there are no more CPPCHECK errors with the C++ code in the Jenkins build.

```
cppcheck \
-I ./ \
-j 4 \
--xml-version=2 \
```